# CUDA Toolkit 5.0 NSight build errors on Mac OS X ML

Tags: macos, cuda, osx-mountain-lion, build-error, nsight

I have strange thing happened to my CUDA Toolkit 5.0.
Few days ago both XCode and NSight Eclipse plugin lost ability to build even simplest CUDA related projects. XCode successfully building projects with custom build rule for C++ source files:

```
    nvcc "INPUT_FILE_NAME"
```

But console output shows that run failed

```
    error: executable doesn't exist: '/Users/geraldus/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CUDA_Hello_World-gzfzqivvsmeamfghnovopxapkdsz/Build/Products/Debug/CUDA Hello World'
    error: failed to launch '/Users/geraldus/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CUDA_Hello_World-gzfzqivvsmeamfghnovopxapkdsz/Build/Products/Debug/CUDA Hello World' -- SBTarget is invaliderror: failed to launch '/Users/geraldus/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CUDA_Hello_World-gzfzqivvsmeamfghnovopxapkdsz/Build/Products/Debug/CUDA Hello World' -- SBTarget is invalid
```

And Eclipse NSight output always shows that .o file is missing.

```
    **** Build of configuration Release for project Simple CUDA RT ****

    make all 
    Building file: ../src/Simple CUDA RT.cu
    Invoking: NVCC Compiler
    nvcc -O3 -gencode arch=compute_20,code=sm_20 -gencode arch=compute_35,code=sm_35 -odir "src" -M -o "src/Simple CUDA RT.d" "../src/Simple CUDA RT.cu"
    nvcc -O3   "src/Simple CUDA RT.o" "../src/Simple CUDA RT.cu"
    i686-apple-darwin11-llvm-g++-4.2: src/Simple CUDA RT.o: No such file or directory
    make: *** [src/Simple CUDA RT.o] Error 1

    **** Build Finished ****
```

How can I fix it? Is it a bug or my incorrect actions?

**UPDATE [10:03 UTC 6 NOV 2012]**

I've tried to rebuild CUDA samples this way:

```
    cd /Developer/NVIDIA/CUDA-5.0/samples
    make clean
    make
```

Everything was built without errors, binaries were successfully generated and they works. But still the same situation with XCode and Eclipse (even after reinstalling Eclipse and CUDA Toolkit)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a permissions issue. Verify the build folder (and all the files in it) are writable by the current user.

**Update**
Turns out the actual problem with Nsight EE was spaces in the file name.

Comment: I've cheched project folders - they are all writable and readable. Also, I've added to /Developer folder (and for all contained folders) read and write permissions for my user. It is not solved my issue. Maybe I should look another folders, e.g. temporary folder or etc.?

Comment: Can you try removing spaces from the source file name?

Comment: I can't belive it's true, but @Eugene thank you a lot! Almost a week of headache! Removing of whitespaces completely resovled the issue with NSight! But still troubles with XCode. Looks like target build rule should be more complex rather `nvcc "INPUT_FILE_NAME"`, maybe there is a way to pass to nvcc compiler other options?

Comment: I'll post answer for NSight. And XCode build rules configuration is an another question.